# Wrapping text around image in Content Builder - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, content-builder

Can I wrap a text around an image in a free form or html content block in SFMC Content Builder? I would like to have white text (i.e. unsubscribe, preference center, some small general data on thje sender) on a blue-colored image as background. If it is possible, what would be the correct html/css code for that?

Comment: Text over an image is supported, but ESPs handle this differently.  You'll need to account for microsoft office products which do not allow for text over images.  Utilizing the `<!--IF MSO-->` tag will be necessary to utilize a plain blue background color.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems more relevant to general HTML email development than anything specific to SFMC. You'll need to use VML in order to ensure the background renders effectively within non-supported clients (looking at you Outlook).

[Here's a great site](https://backgrounds.cm/) for generating this code. Just add your text within this to accomplish what you need.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't express myself right. I actually meant can I embedd text into image; that is, write text on an image as a background. Howerver, if the link you provided is relevant to this also, then I guess I know what to do.

Comment: Yep, that's what the link will provide you with. That's base code for getting a background image to work across clients. All that you need to do is place your content after the final <td> in the generated code (and before the closing tags). You can use tables/text/whatever there to align everything over your background. If this is helpful, please mark my post as answered. Thanks!